# Feature detection with opencv fails with seg fault

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I have the following code

```
cv::initModule_nonfree();
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("someFileNameHere",cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
// image.data is true, cv::imshow() dispalys the image
detector->detect(image, keypoints_1); // seg fault here
```

What can be the reason of the seg fault? I tried running gdb on it with hope that the library has enough meta data, but the stack ends at the call to `detect()`

Comment: It's not `imread`? You include a filename in your code? I think openCV fails ungracefully if you don't give a filename for imread. The other reason could be that you need `cv::detect` instead of `detect`.

Comment: @mprat Sry, I was not explicit, there is a file name, I thought saying that that image.data is true would imply that...

Comment: check, if your detector is valid: `detector.empty()`  (yes, with a dot, not pointer)

Comment: @berak that would seg fault as well. Both `detector->empty()` and `(*detector).empty()`

Comment: just saying, you're actually checking if the cv::Ptr is empty. but if so - it did not give you a SURF detector. are you running some weird os, that restricts you from running nonfree stuff ? did you build the opencv libs, or get them via some ppm ?

Comment: @berek I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. How would it be correct with the nonzero stuff? If you mean the one namespace with `xfeatured2d` I get an error that `xfeature2d is not a namespace of cv::`

Answer (score 27):

I have got into similar problem in Python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np;

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
detector.empty() # <- segfault
keypoints = detector.detect(image) # <- segfault
```

I managed to solve the issue like this [[source](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/BlobDetector/blob.py#L34)]:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np;

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

ver = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
if int(ver[0]) < 3 :
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
else : 
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

detector.empty() # <- now works
keypoints = detector.detect(image) # <- now works
```

Not sure how much is this applicable to the C++ API, but there may be some change in ver3 there as well.

Comment: I am using openCV 4.2, and I can verify that using `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create` worked for me whereas `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector` was causing a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

*cv::Mat image* is an empty image when you call detector->detect.

When you call cv::imread, you have to set the first paramter to an non-empty string.

Comment: Sry, I was not explicit, there is a file name, I thought saying that that image.data is true would imply that...

Comment: ha, sorry, i was careless and missed the comments. I think maybe the seg fault was caused by some runtime version mismatch. I suggest rebuilding opencv  from src with your own gcc toolchain.